# Displaying number of drafts in Posts section of admin sidebar

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, sidebar, draft, count

Is there a WP plugin to show the number of drafts in the *Posts* section of the admin sidebar in the same way that the number of available updates is shown? I’m looking for something like the following example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Quick Review Post Access](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-review-post-access/) (Figure 1) which does the trick. It’s not perfect; I was hoping for the little circle, but this works just as well, and even better, it links directly to the page with non-drafts filtered out, making it even easier to keep track of and work with incomplete posts. It even works for pending and future posts as well.

It’s simple enough to make it use the circle (Figure 2) by simply editing the file `Quick_Review_Post_Access.php` as so:

```
- add_submenu_page( $path, __( 'Drafts' ), sprintf( __( 'Drafts (%d)' ), $num_posts->draft ), $post_type->cap->edit_posts, "edit.php?post_type=$name&post_status=draft" );
+ add_submenu_page( $path, __( 'Drafts' ), sprintf( __( 'Drafts <span class="update-plugins" title="Drafts"><span class="update-count">%d</span></span>' ), $num_posts->draft ), $post_type->cap->edit_posts, "edit.php?post_type=$name&post_status=draft" );

- add_submenu_page( $path, __( 'Pending' ), sprintf( __( 'Pending (%d)' ), $num_posts->pending ), $post_type->cap->edit_posts, "edit.php?post_type=$name&post_status=pending" );
+ add_submenu_page( $path, __( 'Pending' ), sprintf( __( 'Pending <span class="update-plugins" title="Pending"><span class="update-count">%d</span></span>' ), $num_posts->pending ), $post_type->cap->edit_posts, "edit.php?post_type=$name&post_status=pending" );

- add_submenu_page( $path, __( 'future' ), sprintf( __( 'future (%d)' ), $num_posts->future ), $post_type->cap->edit_posts, "edit.php?post_type=$name&post_status=future" );
+ add_submenu_page( $path, __( 'Future' ), sprintf( __( 'Future <span class="update-plugins" title="Future"><span class="update-count">%d</span></span>' ), $num_posts->future ), $post_type->cap->edit_posts, "edit.php?post_type=$name&post_status=future" );
```

The only note is that the plugin’s requirements are messed up, so you’ll get a warning about compatibility:

> Requires: 2.0.2 or higher
>
> Compatible up to: 1.0.1

However, the description specifically says that it is compatible with WP3.0+.

---

**Figure 1:** Quick Review Post Access

[image: Quick Review Post Access screenshot]

**Figure 2:** Quick Review Post Access modification

[image: QRPA modification]

Comment: (Like many, I’ve gotten so used to turning to Google to search that it hadn’t even occurred to me to use the search function of the WP add-plugin page, which is where I eventually found QRPA. Though to be fair, WP’s find-plugin search function is not as effective as Google’s, so it returned 14 pages of results and I had to manually search through them to weed out unrelated hits.)

Comment: You may try my [custom WP search](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=008094839757605916882%3Af6pwe-gmjka). Searches in wp.org _and_ WPSE (and some other sites).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I’ll have to add a link to that in the add-plugin page (though in this case, I can’t find QRPA with that GCS at all).

Comment: @Synetech, I just updated my WP plugins and got a pleasant surprise. Apparently [someone noticed this page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/good-but-needs-styling-mod) and told the author of QRPA about it, so the author implemented the mod in the latest update. ☺